# Add Fonts to Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts

Added a font to my rails 3.2 Ruby 1.9 App that works on my local but not after i push it to heroku.

1- I made sure the font is not installed on my local machine. 
2- added my font file to a fonts directory i created in the /app/assets directory
3- added the following code to my application.rb file

```
#precompile fonts
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/

#add fonts directory to assets pipeline
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

4- added the following to my application.css.scss file

```
 @font-face {
   font-family: Steinerlight;
   src: url('Steinerlight.ttf')format('truetype');
 }
```

5- called the font in my css file like so:

```
 font-family: "Steinerlight", sans-serif;
```

5- i made sure the font name in the css file is exactly the same as the file name in the app/assets/fonts directory

When i precompile restart server on my local the page shows up with the font style i added. (again the font is not installed on my computer).

Problem is when I precompile and push the app to heroku the page is styled with the secondary font (sans-serif) not the one i added. any suggestions on what may be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your pushing the font to the server?

Comment: @Drew i dont see how i could not be. all my other assets show up just fine. unless I made a mistake with the precompile code config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It was a browser issue with IE the fonts load fine in firefox and chrome

added ie specific syntax and it works fine

```
  src: url('Steinerlight.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('Steinerlight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
```

Comment: Also, just as a heads up, in case you wind up using a CDN in the future, firefox does not support font's served from a CDN